# How to get the value of a textbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I upgraded a VB WinForms 6.0 project to WinForms 2019 (VB.NET). I need to get the value of a textbox from one form (class) into another but get nothing back.

In VB6, I used to be able to call out my text this way:

```
MsgBox Form1.MyBox.Text
```

With VB 2019, I noticed that the "Forms" are now classes. I've even tried instantiating the object containing the textbox but still get nothing returned back.

```
Private MyForm1 As New MyForm // Produces an exception error
...
MsgBox(MyForm1.MyBox.Text) //Returns nothing
```

Can someone show me how this is done?

**EDIT**

After fixing the exception error, I have added this into the form where I need to get the value from the other form (class), but my MsgBox produces nothing (null, empty string).

```
Dim Foo As New frmNonSerialize
MsgBox(Foo.txtWorkOrderNo.Text) //Nothing, empty, nada...
```

Comment: Under the properties, for the textbox, change the Modifier to "Public" and try what you did originally again.  Right now I think it's private, can't be seen from outside the instance of that class

Comment: @JimmySmith, Thanks. I just saw your comment. I looked under the properties and the Modifier is already set to Public. Thank you, Jimmy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this 2 different ways in VB.Net. The `Button1` code uses what is now called the *default instance*. You can refer to it just the way your would in VB6. The second way (Button2) is really the .Net way.

Be aware that in order to communicate further with the form created in Button2, you must have a reference to that form. You cannot simply call `Form2.TextBox1.Text| because you are not using the default instance.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Create and instance of the Form2 class
    Dim frm As New Form2
    'Set a property of a member of the Form2 class
    frm.TextBox1.Text = "Hello World"
    'Call a method of the Form2 class
    frm.Show()
    Me.Hide()
End Sub
```

In your edited code...

```
Dim Foo As New frmNonSerialize
MsgBox(Foo.txtWorkOrderNo.Text)
```

You have created a totally new instance of the class `frmNonSerialize`. Of course it has nothing in the text box (unless you set text at design time). It has never even been displayed to the user. The class is the cookie cutter, the instance is the cookie. You can make several cookies with a single cookie cutter. Each cookies then acts independently.

Answer (score 0):

If `New MyForm` throws an exception, then `MyForm1` is not in a valid state.  Since `MyForm1` is not in a valid state, you can't really rely on it.

`MyForm1.MyBox.Text` should work just fine.  But when you say `New MyForm` threw an exception, I think that's at least the main, if not the only, reason you're having trouble.  So fix the exception, and you will have at least partially solved the problem with the `Text` property.

As for how to fix the exception, it really just depends on the situation.  If necessary, you can post another question for that, but try to make sure the question's not a duplicate or something first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Panzercrisis. Here is what I'm able to get from the exception: `-  $exception {"Exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' was thrown."} System.StackOverflowException
`

Comment: Panzercrisis, here is another piece of the exception that might help you see what I'm doing wrong: `Data {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.IDictionary {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}`

Comment: @Nan Not sure about `ListDictionaryInternal`, but otherwise that sounds like infinite recursion.  I think that either `New MyForm` is calling `New MyForm` internally (directly or indirectly), or something else it's creating is doing that.  At that point, `New MyForm` calls `New MyForm` inside of itself, which calls `New MyForm` inside of itself, and so on forever, until the program just runs out of memory; or either another `New <SomeClass>` is doing the equivalent.  As either `New MyForm` or `New <SomeClass>` does that, it may be kind of indirect and going through other methods in between.

Comment: Ahhh!!! Thank you for setting me on the right path! Okay, I see where the recursion is happening. So, I've removed the recursion but how do I echo the textbox value from a different class?